# How to paint only selected tab

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, drawrectangle

I have a tabcontrol with `DrawMode` set to `OwnerDrawFixed`. I have been able to draw the tab and color it `Black` what i want to do is to draw a seperate paint for the selected tab and color it `Gray`. This is my `Draw_Item` event.

```
private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    //This is the code i want to use to color the selected tab (e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, 200, 32);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, 200, 32);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("x", e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Right-17, e.Bounds.Top+4);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(this.tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, Brushes.White, e.Bounds.Left + 12, e.Bounds.Top + 4);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    if (e.Index == activeButton)
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Right - 22, e.Bounds.Top + 4, 20, 20), Color.Blue, ButtonBorderStyle.Inset);
}
```

I have created a global variable `TabPage  current` that i want to use to store the current tab page and in `SelectedIndexChanged` event i have assigned the selected tab to the variable and called `Invalidate();` to force repaint of the tab.

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    current = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
    tabControl1.Invalidate();
}
```

Now where I'm stuck is how to color only the selected tab in the `DrawItem` event.

My Question now is how do i check for selected tab in the `DrawItem` event and paint only the selected tab.

Comment: Well, that looks familiar, not a happy memory. Look at the MSDN article for the Invalidate() method, lots of overloads. If it makes a difference then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant Mehn. There is still a lot i have to learn. I just started to learn the use of rectangle.

Comment: @HansPassant After a lot of googling and research i finally found the answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937905/how-to-paint-only-selected-tab/18938631#18938631

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my question. I modified the global variable to be of `int` datatype and then assigned the index to it in `SelectedIndexChanged`, and then checked for it in the `DrawItem`.

```
int current;
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    current = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
    tabControl1.Invalidate();
}

private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, 200, 32);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("x", e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Right-17, e.Bounds.Top+4);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(this.tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, Brushes.White, e.Bounds.Left + 12, e.Bounds.Top + 4);
    if (e.Index == activeButton)
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Right - 22, e.Bounds.Top + 4, 20, 20), Color.Blue, ButtonBorderStyle.Inset);

    if (e.Index == current)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, 200, 32); 
        e.Graphics.DrawString("x", e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Right - 17, e.Bounds.Top + 4);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, Brushes.White, e.Bounds.Left + 12, e.Bounds.Top + 4);    
    }
}
```

Works fine for me.